# Adding a reset button to a Javascript HTML game?

Tags: javascript

I am second semester, taking a class in Javascript. Basically, we were given the HTML and CSS for a website, and it is supposed to do the following:

It's a number game. The computer generates a number, and you have ten tries to guess this number. If you get to zero, the computer wins, and there is a reset button which should reset all the variables and start again. Only problem is, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to reset the countDown variable after the score reaches 0. Please help. Also we are using only pure Javascript for this course for now. I don't want to cheat, I am more trying to figure out what the issue is that's holding me back.

```js
var countDown = 10;
var computerNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 501) + 1);

function generate() {

    playerNumber = document.getElementById("guess").value;


    if (computerNumber == playerNumber && countDown > 0) {

        alert("Congratulations! You've won!");

    } else if (playerNumber < computerNumber && countDown > 0) {
        countDown--;
        document.getElementById("guesses").value = countDown;
        document.getElementById("result").value = "Too Low";

    } else if (playerNumber > computerNumber && countDown > 0) {
        countDown--;
        document.getElementById("guesses").value = countDown;
        document.getElementById("result").value = "Too High";

    } else if (countDown == 0) {
        alert("Game Over. The Number Was " + computerNumber);

    }

}

function reset() {
    countDown = 10;
    computerNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 501) + 1);
}
```

Comment: I dont see any line that reproduce the error

Comment: is there any loops that use the `generate` function?

Comment: @Hanz The generate function is attached to a button, so when a user enters their number, and presses that button, the function runs. The issue is when the user loses the game, they get the alert, and when the reset button is pressed, the value of countDown is still 0.

Comment: so you see your guess left from the `#guess` element? does it updates when you press the reset button? You could also see the `countDown` variable through browser console though

Comment: @Hanz yes you can, and yes, it resets back to 10, which is the starting number. And the countDown variable I watch in the console tick down to zero, and when the reset button is hit, it continues to start at zero and alert me that I've lost the game.

Comment: update those elements when resetting the game, that might give some vision

Comment: @Hanz I've tried down in the reset function, but it doesn't affect the generate function's countDown variable at all.

Comment: @BrandonK Just wanted to point out that you need to use 3 equal sign when comparing value in javascript, i.e. `===`, not 2.

Comment: Suggestion: declare the `playerNumber` variable. If not declared, assigning a value to `playerNumber` creates a global variable. I strongly suggest writing code in strict mode ([__1__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/strict_mode),__[2__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)) to have the JavaScript compiler generate errors for coding patterns that are known to generate bugs.

Answer (score 0):

In the reset function, you would need to update the element that displays the countDown in the HTML

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to add the reset button in the html:

```html
<input type="button" class="reset-button" value="Reset Count">
```

Then grab that button in your JS below the reset function and attach an eventListener that fires the reset function when clicked:

```js
const resetBtn = document.querySelector('.reset-button')

resetBtn.addEventListener('click', reset )
```

And that's it.

You would probably want the count displayed on the page, too. You could add a line in the reset function that pushes the new value of `countDown` into the html (with element.textContent = countDown.toString(), for example)

If you take a JS class in 2021 you should definitely use const and let instead of var, and let your teacher know why. Using var works, though, but will show a future employer that you're out of touch with what's going on in the JS world.

Comment: Thank you for the help! In my downtime I'll probably be following alongside a more current youtube course or something. I dont think I'll be able to use your suggested code because we havent learned about jQuery or whatever that is quite yet, sadly.

Comment: Don't use jQuery either, that's quite a few years too late. My code is pure javascript, so you could use it in your project. Read up on ES6, the 2015 version of JS where new syntax and syntactic sugar was introduced. There have been releases after that, too, the idea now is new stuff every year so keep yourself up to date. Remember that a lot of what you find on StackOverflow will be 10+ years old. Best of luck to you.

Comment: Thank you. That's excellent advice. I appreciate it!